# deleting pandas dataframe row based condition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe has a column where each row is a string which corresponds to a filename.  I read my data from a JSON file and extract the column like this:

```
df = pd.read_json("mergedJSON.txt",lines=True,orient='columns')
df2 = df.set_index("subject")
for key,value in some_dict.iteritems():
  df2.loc[value,"file_name"].to_csv(outfile,index=False, header=False)
```

I need to drop certain rows from this dataframe based on whether the file is found on disk. Not sure how to do this. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this as the last line

```
df2[df2.file_name.str.contains('stringValue')].loc[value,:].to_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [set_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index),[reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex)
use the filename as index,and then do `df.drop(filename)`.